# How to pass data through a hyperlink to a php page using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to pass data from a hyperlink to a page via a get request using Ajax

Initially I am able to do this without Ajax directly as below

```
 <a id="link" href="page.php?id=12&pid=12" >pass data</a>
```

and I catch below in php

```
<?php $_GET['id'] ?>
<?php $_GET['pid']?>
```

now I want to do this using Ajax so the page does not need to load

I am trying with the below

```
 <a class="choice" id="link" href="page.php?id=12&pid=12" >pass data</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
          
                $(".choice").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.ajax( {
                        <!--insert.php calls the PHP file-->
                        url: "votes.php",
                        method: "get",
                       dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(strMessage) {
                            $("#vote").html(strMessage);
                          
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

but I am unable to get this to work. I need help on the correct implementation of send data using Ajax to my php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a `<script>` tag is required for JavaScript part. Ajax URL can read from `<a>` tag `href` attribute by `$(this).attr('href')`. Also based on your code, a div with `vote` id is needed so `<div id="vote"></div>` added.

```
<a class="choice" id="link" href="page.php?id=12&pid=12" >pass data</a>
<div id="vote"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".choice").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax( {
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            method: "get",
           dataType: 'html',
            success: function(strMessage) {
                $("#vote").html(strMessage);
              
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: fantastic implementation, yes  had my script tag and <div id="vote"></div>. what was missing was the correct url parameter implementation in the Ajax method. Really helpful

Comment: Thanks, my pleasure.

Answer (score -1):

> Document
>     
>
>
>     pass data
>
> ```
> <script>
>     $(document).ready(function() {
>         $("#choice").click(function(e) {
>             e.preventDefault();
>             $.ajax({
>                 url: $(this).attr('href'),
>                 method: "GET",
>                 dataType: 'html',
>                 success: function(strMessage) {
>                     $("#vote").html(strMessage);
>
>                 }
>             });
>         });
>     });
> </script> </body>
> ```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).